# Upload multiple images for a single post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, custom-wordpress-pages

I have been already searching about this issue but didn't get the targeted answer yet.

In every answer I find the solution about 'upload multiple images for a post for image slider'.

I want to upload a thumbnail and a normal image for a post. And want to display that thumbnail image in my home page and that normal image in the post page.

How to do that? Any plugin for that ?

Anybody help please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try custom field in every post. repeater field is best here.

Comment: @DipakDholakiya....  ok...I will try... Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: See this link https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/